# How to run several methods in a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a problem when I want to run several methods not in the main thread. I created a class extends from Runnable and put all my tasks there. There are a lot of tasks actually. Then in the main thread I created a new instance of Thread and passed my runnable class as a parameter, but what I got is that the run method is the only code which executed in the thread, and if call any method inside the runnable class it will execute in the main thread instead of the new thread.

Example:

```java
public class ConnectionManager implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        login();
    }

    public void login() {
        //Login Logic
    }

    public void sendMessage() {
        //Send Message Via TCP Connection
    }

    public void updateInfo() {
        //Update Information
    }

    public void logOut() {
        //LogOut Logic
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to call any of these methods in another thread, so I did this:

```java
public class Login implements SomeInterface {
    private Thread thread;
    private ConnectionManager connection;

    public void main(String[] args) {
        connection = new ConnectionManager();
        thread= new Thread(connection);
        thread.start(); // This will execute the run method and the login process works fine.
    }

    @Override
    public void someCallback() {
        connection.sendMessage();//this call is not executed and block the main thread !!
    }
}
```

What am I supposed to do to run all my methods in another thread without making a new thread for each method?

Comment: If you're working with android I suggest go read this before creating threads to execute tasks. https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html This explains the best threading implementations for the task you want to execute. For example you wouldn't use a normal thread when you want to execute a small operation, there you would rather use an AsyncTask because it's a well rounded thread implementation

Comment: yeah i know AsyncTask but it work only for one time and one task , i wanna execute more than 20 task each in time and not at the same time .

Comment: "What I got is that the run method is the only code which executed in the thread, and if call any method inside the runnable class it will execute in the main thread instead of the new thread": this is untrue. What made you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split your logic

```
public class Logger implements Runnable {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       // login logic here;
   }
}

public class MessegeSender implements Runnable {
  @Override
   public void run() {
        //Send Message Via TCP Connection
  }
}

public class MessegeSender implements Runnable {
  @Override
   public void run() {
        //Update Information
  }
}

public class MessegeSender implements Runnable {
  @Override
   public void run() {
        //LogOut Logic
  }
}
```

And then in some client:

```
Runnable logger = new Logger(credentials);
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(logger);
```

Comment: Thank you but Am i need to create a new Runnable class for each method ? I have more than 20 task !

Comment: Thats an object oriented design. The profit is - you do not get a mess in a one 4000 class. And you can replace and add new features without changing the interface used to run your tasks. If you got one class with 20 methods, in order to run new task, you are to add method, new thread code etc. With my solution, you are adding one class and that's it. Remember about Single responsibility and OpenClosed principle

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how threads work in java. One possibility is to use Actors in java. You will have to download the Akka framework here:http://akka.io/downloads/.
Actors works by messages, they act in a separate process and are even driven messages. In other words depending on the message you send to the actor it will process a corresponding method.

Check in the following link for instances: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/untyped-actors.html

The method run equivalent in java actors is onReceive().
And to send a message to the actor, myActor.tell(...)

Hope this helps you!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Well, that is the way threads work in Java. When You call connection.sendMessage() Your method just treats ConnectionManager  and runs it's code. You need to execute Your method in another threads run(), or it will not run. Perhaps You need a way to comunicate with Your thread to make it execute a method in run() or just explore the possibilities that Future objects give You?

Comment: so when i call connection.sendMessage() it will execute in the main thread , OK i got it , but how can i make it run in another thread , Do i have to make a new class for every method and then pass them to a new Thread object ?

Comment: @RamzyAbuShaaban
Either You need to create a new class, or an anonymous thread class, or You can use future objects, which let You get the asynchroneous method result.

Try this: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/java-concurrency-tutorial-callable.html

Comment: Thank you but my problem was that i can't call the methods inside the Runnable class from the main thread , and i don't wanna create a new Runnable class for each method to be execute in another thread , Can you please explain your solution with Future object by example ?

Comment: @RamzyAbuShaaban future object will just simplify creating a new thread object, and synchronizing with the asynchroneous method result retrieval. 
Sorry, but it is not like a problem. It is how Java, is created and works: by the end of the run method execution, it is not a separate thread anymore, its just an object. 

The way You want to do it is impossible, You need to either create a new class (propably anonymous) or make Your thread wait inside the run method, for a command to execute.

Answer (score -1):

That's how does Runnable or Multithread handling work.

You should never call the run() directly and only this function and other function calls inside this function are executed in the new thread.

Basically your Runnable class should only contains one public function: the run() and you should not call it directly...

I suggest you to put other functions in their own classes. As you can see the workflow is not continuous, sendMessage() is not called directly after login() (otherwise you can do it inside run() and don't need that someCallback()).

Otherwise what should that new thread supposed to do in the time between? block and wait for sendMessage()? That's not a good design. So you should start a new thread for sendMessage().

Comment: Thank you but i have more than 20 task in that class and i think it's not option to create a new class for each task right!